# Simple Socket Server in C for Windows

Tags: c, socket, windows, server

I have taken the code from a tutorial of Microsoft webpage.
Of course, the example is for illustration only but I wanted to organize it and make it clear in order to understand it a little more.

Here the link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/complete-server-code

It almost the same but structured diffently. It already works but I think it can be better. Any help or tip will be apreciated

`````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27016"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

int receiveBuffer(SOCKET *ClientSocket)
{
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int bytesReceived, iSendResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {
        bytesReceived = recv(*ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (bytesReceived > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", bytesReceived);
            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(*ClientSocket, recvbuf, bytesReceived, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        } else if (bytesReceived == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());         
            return 1;
        }
    } while (bytesReceived > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    bytesReceived = shutdown(*ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());        
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

SOCKET acceptSocket(SOCKET *ListenSocket)
{
    // Accept a client socket
    SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(*ListenSocket, NULL, NULL); 
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        //closesocket(ListenSocket);
        //WSACleanup();
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    return ClientSocket;
}

int listenSocket(SOCKET *ListenSocket, int backlog)
{
    if ( listen( *ListenSocket, backlog ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
        printf( "Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        //closesocket(ListenSocket);        
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    return 0;
}

SOCKET createSocket(struct addrinfo *result)
{   
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        //freeaddrinfo(result);     
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    return ListenSocket;
}

int bindSocket(SOCKET *ListenSocket, struct addrinfo *result)
{
    int iResult = bind( *ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);    
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    return 0;
}

int initializeWinSock()
{
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;
    /* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }
}

int prepareSocket(SOCKET *ListenSocket, SOCKET *ClientSocket, struct addrinfo *result)
{
    initializeWinSock();

    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iResult;
    int err;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof (hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);        
        return 1;
    }

    *ListenSocket = createSocket(result);
    //SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    err = bindSocket(ListenSocket, result);
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    if(err != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    err = listenSocket(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if(err != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    *ClientSocket = acceptSocket(ListenSocket); 
    if(*ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        return 1;
    }

    err = receiveBuffer(ClientSocket);  
    if(err != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    int err = prepareSocket(&ListenSocket, &ClientSocket, result);

    WSACleanup();
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    closesocket(ClientSocket);

    if(err != 0) {
        printf("There is an error, we're trying to solve it, goodbye\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

````
`````